# Google Scatter Charts point on top of another point

Tags: charts, google-visualization, scatter

I'm using Google Scatter Charts and have it all fixed and running but I have a problem with some of the data that I use.

In my data I can have multiply points with same X and Y coordinates so when they are displayed on my chart some of them are not able to be clicked.

Does anyone know any solution for this?

Comment: I'm also looking for a 'grouping' method and showing a larger `pointSize` however I am unable to do so by each point, but only for the whole set (pointSize control)

Comment: I really want to know this too!